# Installing RMagick on Mac OS X with MacPorts

Tags: ruby, macos, imagemagick, rubygems, rmagick

With the MacPorts version of ImageMagick 6.4.4 installed, I'm getting an error installing the RMagick gem.

```
/opt/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb update rmagick
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.2... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc-4.0... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.7.0. Can't find Magick-config in
    /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Commands:
    /Users/jason/.bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:
    /usr/local/ec2-api-tools/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:
    /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

I've installed older versions of rmagick successfully. I've seen references to a dev package of ImageMagick, but it doesn't seem to be available from MacPorts.

How can I install RMagick 2.7 on Mac OS X with ImageMagick 6.4.4 from MacPorts?

Answer (score 22):

I suggest using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) instead of Macports. After installing Homebrew, run:

```
brew install imagemagick
gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this from the command line before installing the rmagick gem:

```
sudo port install tiff -macosx imagemagick +q8 +gs +wmf
```

Also have you read the installation documentation [here](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-osx.html) ?

Comment: This was also helpful because of the reference back to rmagick's page and because it installed ImageMagick properly using MacPorts.

Answer (score 4):

The install script can't find Magick-config in your path.  Did you use a non-standard install location when you installed ImageMagick through MacPorts?  Usually it goes into /opt/local/bin/

You can see where MacPorts put your Magick-config by running:

> port contents ImageMagick

If you find it listed there, then make sure that the directory is included in your PATH and rerun the rmagick install.

Comment: Although rather old, this was really good advice, I got rmagick installed using the following command:

PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick

Comment: Yup this was my issue as well

Answer (score 1):

I've run the install command, but I keep getting this error:

> /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- RMagick2.so (LoadError)

Turns out it correctly builds the shared object file, but the name is "wrong".

The file I get is named `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.11.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle`; renaming it to `RMagick2.so` fixes this issue.